# Combining two queries

Tags: 7, database

I want to list All the images that are present in more than one article.

My setup is like this. I have a content type "article" and it has a field of type "Field Collection" (field_medias), the field_medias has the following fields: field_media (without "s") and field_caption.

I can select all the images with the following EntityFieldQuery

```
  $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'field_collection_item')
                  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'field_medias')
                  ->fieldCondition('field_media')
                  ->execute();
```

And I can select all the articles with the following query:

```
 $result1 = $query1->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
                   ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
                   ->fieldCondition('field_medias') //has a image
                   ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
                   ->execute();
```

How can I select all the images that belong to at least 2 articles. Is that possible using a single EntityFieldQuery?

As I have hundreds of thousands of articles and hundreds of thousands of images I have to avoid resource hungry queries.